# move_uploaded_file não move ficheiros

Tags: php, html, mysql, file-upload

Eu tenho um *form* (em php, queria perguntar se funciona sem problema?) para inserir imagens (o *path* delas) e quando eu insiro aparece a notificação que foram inseridas na base de dados mas a imagem não move para a pasta que peço.

Este é o código que fiz para transferir:

```
<?php

    include '../conn.php';
    mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $imagem    = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];
    $img_name = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];

    $dir      = "../imagens/viaturas/";
    $path     = $dir.$img_name;

    move_uploaded_file( $imagem, $path );    


    $sql = "INSERT INTO carros_img(id_fk, img) VALUES ($id, '$img_name')";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    echo "<script>
             document.location.href = '../admin/carros.php?id=$id';
     </script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>
            alert('Imagem não enviada');
            document.location.href = '../admin/quem.php?id=$id';
        </script>";  
     }  
?>
```

O *path* da imagem aparece na bd mas a imagem não move de pasta. Algum problema com o código?

Comment: Dá algum erro? Talvez tenha a haver com permissões

Comment: Não, não dá erro nenhum apenas não move a imagem.

Comment: Tem permissões para escrever na pasta que refere?

Comment: O caminho da pasta está correto ?

Comment: O caminho está certo mas permissão não sei. Como se faz permissão
?

Comment: basta ver as propriedades da pasta.. mas eventualmente nao será esse o problema.
acrescente isto,  no seu codigo e veja se lhe surge algum erro:
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Coloque no inicio desse código essas três linhas: `ini_set('display_errors',1);`
`ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);`
`error_reporting(E_ALL);` execute o código se não for ele te mostra o erro.

Comment: Bruno, publique na pergunta a arvore do seu projeto, incluindo a pasta onde está executando este script e a pasta onde quer salvar por favor!

Comment: Permissão 755 na pasta onde os arquivos vão ser movidos. Se nenhum erro é apresentado os caminhos parecem estar corretos.